# How to find out HTML Code of a certain Font Glyph?

Tags: fonts, truetype, eot

I am searching for a way to find a certain font glyph. I am using DinPro, which has two different "at" Symbols. As the standard symbol is not the one I want to use, I am searching for the html code to get the second one. Any chance to find that?

Comment: Not if the second one is an OpenType Alternate (because "the html code" would be the same). If you're lucky there is a CSS rule to select alternates, but that is a work-in-progress and not widely supported.

Comment: Thanks for that information. I've done a workaround now by creating this one glyph as a svg symbol and use it in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was an OpenType Alternate i've found a solution that will work in modern browsers:

```
-moz-font-feature-settings: "ss01=1";
-ms-font-feature-settings: "ss01";
-webkit-font-feature-settings: "ss01";
-o-font-feature-settings: "ss01";
font-feature-settings: "ss01";
```

Older browsers will still show the other symbol, which is enough for me.